# How to divide a set of numbers so that it is always between 0 to 100?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a set of numbers whose max can be in thousands, I want to have it's equivalent between 0 to 100. So as to use it in [Bootstrap progress bar](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp).

```
$scope.events.stabilized = function() {
    console.warn('Event "stabilized" triggered');
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    if ($scope.visProgress >= 90) {
        $scope.visAvailable = true;
        $scope.visProgress = 100;
    }
};

$scope.events.stabilizationProgress = function() {
    $scope.visAvailable = false;
    /*var total = 100, iter = Math.round(arguments[0].iterations/100);
    if (typeof arguments[0] != "undefined") {
        total = arguments[0].total;
    }*/
    $scope.visProgress = Math.round(arguments[0].iterations / 10);
    //console.log(arguments[0].total + ", " + arguments[0].iterations+", "+$scope.visProgress);
    console.warn('Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered');
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
};

$scope.events.stabilizationIterationsDone = function() {
    console.warn('Event "stabilizationIterationsDone" triggered');
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    $scope.visAvailable = true;
    $scope.visProgress = 100;
};
```

Console output

```
 Event "stabilized" triggered
 Object {iterations: 0}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 50, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 100, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 150, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 200, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 250, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: , total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: , total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 400, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 450, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 500, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 550, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 600, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 650, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 700, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 750, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 800, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 850, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 900, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 950, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1000, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1050, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1100, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1150, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1200, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1250, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1400, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1450, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1500, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1550, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1600, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1650, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1700, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1750, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1800, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1850, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1900, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 1950, total: 2000}
 Event "stabilizationIterationsDone" triggered
 Event "stabilized" triggered
 Object {iterations: 2001}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, divide each number by the max and then multiply by 100.

Comment: Thanks I got it working `Math.round((arguments[0].iterations / arguments[0].total) * 100)`. For others solution is explained in **Kailas** answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution seems simple, in maths : take the percentage of the value, your calculation is almost correct, just add a couple of paranthesis:

```
Math.round((arguments[0].iterations / arguments[0].total)*100);
```

So if suppose you have the case:

```
Event "stabilizationProgress" triggered
 Object {iterations: 900, total: 2000}
```

the calc should be:

```
Math.round((arguments[0].iterations / arguments[0].total)*100);
Math.round((900 / 2000)*100);
Math.round((9 / 20)*100);
Math.round((0.45)*100);
=45
```

**What happened with your original calculation was:**

```
Math.round(arguments[0].iterations / arguments[0].total)*100;
Math.round(900 / 2000)*100
Math.round(0.45)*100
```

**Reason:**

1) Math.round() method will give you 0 for Math.round(0.45) {ie a value < 0.5 but greater than 0}, that's why you were getting: 0*100 = 0.

2) And for some value like Math.round(0.75) {value > 0.5 but < 1} this method will return 1, that's why you got: 1*100= 100

In Essence your formula will give you only two values 0 or 100. Makes sense?

**Reference:**[Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: Thanks but Wheeldog's answer helped me solve the problem first as you explained in your solution.